# Use cookies in curl to set language

Tags: curl, web

I need to `curl | grep` some data from a webpage but *after* setting language to English. In a browser, I can do this by clicking on a link.

I first get the `SelectCulture` page and save the cookie in a file, then I use it to get the page I need:

```
#!/bin/bash

#tmp_file="$(mktemp)"
tmp_file="cookies"

curl -s \
    --location \
    --cookie "$tmp_file" \
    --cookie-jar "$tmp_file" \
    --user-agent Mozilla/4.0 \
    --data-urlencode "ReturnUrl=http://it.bca-europe.com/Default.aspx" \
    "http://it.bca-europe.com/Home/SelectCulture/en-GB-BDIT" | egrep "Ospite|Guest"

curl -s \
    --location \
    --cookie "$tmp_file" \
    --user-agent Mozilla/4.0 \
    "http://it.bca-europe.com/Default.aspx" | egrep "Ospite|Guest"
```

The problem is that on first run, when the `cookies` file does not exist yet, somehow the language doesn't change (you get italian *Ospite* instead of *Guest*), whereas the script works from the second run.

This, for example, avoids the need to use a temporary file instead of a static file. Moreover, weirdly, I can't get it to work in a single run.

Any advice?

Comment: Why would the *first* `curl` call need the `--cookie` *and* the `--cookie-jar`?  From what I gather, the first call should fill the jar but it should not need (an empty?) cookie at all.  I think this could be the culprit, i.e. why it works the *second* time (since the jar is non-emtpy)...maybe.

Comment: @sr_: you are right, it's overkill, it's the result of some trials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser usually sends a list of accepted languages with every request. CMSes often use this when no cookie is set. (In theory, the cookie is just a fallback and the language settings are correct.) This results in  `<span>Hello Guest</span>` for me:

```
curl -s  --location -H 'Accept-Language: en' "http://it.bca-europe.com/Home/SelectCulture/en-GB-BDIT" | egrep "Ospite|Guest"
```

Comment: and this is right what I was looking for, thank you.